# Form doesn't close on submit button using ng-Show, ng-disabled

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to create a form to add new users. The submit button remains disabled until I fill up all the textboxes. But once I fill up all the textboxes correctly, it gets enabled.

Here is the problem. After I click the submit button, the user gets added into the table, but the form doesn't close. The textboxes clears and all of them displays the error messages.

I have also added the style- input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty{border:1px solid red;} before the head tag.

```html
<form name="addForm"class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="addEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" ng-model="newUser.email" required>
                                    <span ng-show="addForm.addEmail.$dirty && addForm.addEmail.$error.required">Enter Email</span>
                                    <span ng-show="addForm.addEmail.$dirty && addForm.addEmail.$error.email">Invalid Email</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">First Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addFirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" ng-model="newUser.firstName" required>
                                    <span ng-show="addForm.addFirstName.$dirty && addForm.addFirstName.$error.required">Enter First Name</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addLastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" ng-model="newUser.lastName" required>
                                    <span ng-show="addForm.addLastName.$dirty && addForm.addLastName.$error.required">Enter Last Name</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Contact</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="addContact" placeholder="Enter Contact" ng-model="newUser.contact" required>
                                    <span ng-show="addForm.addContact.$dirty && addForm.addContact.$error.required">Enter Contact</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Role</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addRole" placeholder="Enter Role" ng-model="newUser.role" required>
                                    <span ng-show="addForm.addRole.$dirty && addForm.addRole.$error.required">Enter Role</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>                        

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <button ng-disabled="addForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveUser()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
   <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it :

1. Put my form in a div

   ```
   <div class="contact-form">
       <form method="post" action="sendemail.php" id="contact-form">
           <!-- FORM CONTENT HERE -->
       </form>
   </div>
   ```
2. Then, add this to your script file (note that the code `$('#contact-form').hide()` will hide your form after the post) :

   ```
   //Contact Form Validation
   $('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var $inputs = $('#contact-form :input');

       // not sure if you wanted this, but I thought I'd add it.
       // get an associative array of just the values.
       var data = {};
       $inputs.each(function() {
           data[this.name] = $(this).val();
       });

       $.ajax({
           url: '/send-mail',
           data: data,
           method: 'post'
       })
       .then(function success(res) {
            console.log('Success!');
            var s1 = document.getElementById('contact-title');
            s1.innerHTML = 'Form sent with success.';
            $('#contact-form').hide()
       })
       .catch(function error(err) {
            console.error(err);
            var s2 = document.getElementById('contact-title');
            s2.innerHTML = 'Errors sending your form...';
            $('#contact-form').hide()
       })
   });
   ```

Hope you can find your answer here.

Comment: @Vaibhav Shankar, glad I could help!